# How can I convert my pygame game to an .exe

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe, cx-freeze

I know py2exe isn't compatible with Python 3.3(which I use) I tried using cx_freeze it worked but I need to have my files with my .exe also. I have a folder that has images that I use for my game and without them the game doesn't work. Anybody know how I can convert my 3.3 pygame with a folder to an .exe? P.S I'm on Windows 7

I figured it out

Comment: Have you looked at `py3exe`, the official `py2exe` branch for 2.7+/3.2+ code? I have no idea if it's in a stable/usable state yet, but it's probably easier to try it and/or ask the maintainers than to guess (especially for people who are reading this months in the future).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include other "data files" along with your code in the `.exe`, use a setup script to list all the files needed. These two links should help you: [FAQs- Using Data Files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) and [distutils setup script](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils).

Also, another alternative is to use Qt's resource system to embed the data in your code. See these two links: [The Qt Resource System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html) and [PyQT by example](http://ralsina.me/stories/BBS49.html). (But if you're using pygame, you probably aren't also using Qt)